# How to display an image in HTML retrieve from Mongodb using Java or Spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I need to display the Image based on     ***FindById()***.
So through Rest Call, I am able to fetch the image from MongoDB. But I want to display that image to a user in Brower in Html.

Following is the JSON with I get from Database.  
For me now the challenge is how I will render this Image to User on Browser

```
 {
   "_id" : ObjectId("59f2e116a8e60d335f4bd6bb"),
   "filename" : "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
   "aliases" : null,
   "chunkSize" : NumberLong(261120),
   "uploadDate" : ISODate("2017-10-27T07:32:38.793Z"),
   "length" : NumberLong(879394),
   "contentType" : null,
   "md5" : "076e3caed758a1c18c91a0e9cae3368f"
 }
```

Comment: Can you edit this into a more specific question? There are hundreds of ways this could be answered, and, as it stands, it's way too broad for StackOverflow. You should probably start with a simple Java tutorial for how to serve an image in HTML.

Comment: I just want to render this image in my HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your **Base Url + FileName** to reder the image in html

for example

> you can pass your **domain URL** path where the image is hosted 
>   + **image
>   name** to complete the url to the image.

like this:

```
 <img ng-src="http://localhost:5000/api/images/{{image-name-here}}" alt=""/>
```

or

```
 <img ng-src="http://myImageDomainExample/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt=""/>
```